# COM Add-In > Dispose objects correctly

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, marshalling

In an Outlook Add-In, objects seem to be kept in memory. As a result when the Add-In is active in Outlook, .eml files can only be opened once. When trying a second time, I get:

```
We can't open [filename]. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it ...
```

When the Add-In is disabled, .eml files can be opened multiple times without any issue.
In Add-In code, I placed a Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(obj) at multiple places but it did not help. The code is fairly long and spread of over multiple files. It might be that I missed a release.

Is there any way to easily troubleshoot the situation and identify the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to comment out most of your code and bring it back a few lines at a time until the problem comes back.

As a sledgehammer solution, try to call GC.Collect() after you are done.

Comment: Thanks Dimitry, a few hours and a lot of breakpoints later, I finally found it.

Comment: I am creating a wrapinspector around the Outlook Inspector but only if the current object is an appointment otherwise I used to be doing nothing. Now in case of an email being inspected, I added Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(inspector); GC.Collect();GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Comment: Did you use the "as" operator? If you did, it most likely created an implicit variable that you cannot explicitly release using Marshal.ReleaseComObject.